# Need a way to reset the data entered in the form to prevent repeated data entry on refresh

Tags: php, html

My code works fine with entering the data into my csv file. But the issue I've ran into is that the programme will still add new entries due to the variables storing the previous entry. Here my php code;

```
<?php 
session_start();

$books = fopen("Books.csv", "a+");
$ISBN = $_POST['ISBN'];
$Title = $_POST['Title'];
$Description = $_POST['Description'];

//$bookEntry = fgetcsv($books);
if($ISBN !== null && $Title !== null && $Description !== null){
    $txtEntry = '"' . $ISBN . '"' . ',' . '"' . $Title . '"' . ',' . '"' . $Description . '"' . "\n";
    fwrite($books,$txtEntry);
}
else{}
?>
```

I've tried setting the ISBN, Title and Description as null in the if loop but that didn't seem to work so I have a feeling that it may be the html that's keeping the data stored.

Comment: If you hit Refresh in your browser directly after submitting a form, it will submit the form again (which of course runs the PHP script again with the same input data). You should have got a warning in your browser before it did this - unless you've switched them off, of course. The simple solution is not to refresh your page after submitting a form (after all, why would you ever need or want to)? If you think your users are realistically still likely to do this for some reason, you could implement the [POST-redirect-GET pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to avoid it.

Comment: Ah okay, I've fixed it by separating it into its own file and using the action on the form to call it.